# Prevent having several times the same array in php

Tags: php

I use the mikealmond tool to parse the PHP API of MusicBrainz (the documentation is available [here](https://github.com/mikealmond/MusicBrainz)). I face such a simple problem that I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. I try to recover all recordings for a given artist (by David Guetta for my tests).

Here is the code :

```
public function getRecordingsWithArtistMbdi() {
    $arrayRecordings = array();
    $includes = array('artist-credits', 'tags');
    try {
        $recordings = $this->mb->browseRecording('artist', '302bd7b9-d012-4360-897a-93b00c855680', $includes);
        $countRecordings = $recordings['recording-count'];
        foreach ($recordings['recordings'] as $recording) {
            if (!in_array($recording['id'], $arrayRecordings)) {
                $record = array(
                    'titre' => isset($recording['title']) ? $recording['title'] : null,
                    'duree' => isset($recording['length']) ? $recording['length'] : null,
                    'tags' => isset($recording['tags']) ? $recording['tags'] : null,
                    'artist-credit' => isset($recording['artist-credit']) ? $recording['artist-credit'] : null
                );
                $arrayRecordings[$recording['id']] = $record;
            }
            var_dump($arrayRecordings);
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

And here is the beginning of what I get as a result of `var_dump` :

```
array (size=1)
  '11329ba1-2645-4bbb-92ae-b2929188d51c' => // Ok, it is saved now
    array (size=4)
      'titre' => string 'ACDC' (length=4)
      'duree' => int 241786
      'tags' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'artist-credit' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
array (size=2)
  '11329ba1-2645-4bbb-92ae-b2929188d51c' => // Double information
    array (size=4)
      'titre' => string 'ACDC' (length=4)
      'duree' => int 241786
      'tags' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'artist-credit' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
  '124c53b9-6cc5-4f46-a811-598e8f2947fb' => 
    array (size=4)
      'titre' => string 'Baby When the Light' (length=19)
      'duree' => null
      'tags' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'artist-credit' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
```

As you can see, the first array is recorded but despite the **`if (!in_array($recording['id'], $arrayRecordings)) {`**, it is learned each time. How to solve this problem with my current code?

It is pure php problem, the problem is not with the parse of API !

Comment: instead of `in_array` I'd simply use `isset($arrayRecordings[$recording['id']])`, why loop through array when you can check for exact item

Comment: @slash197 : Same result

Comment: What do you mean by double information? Your are dumping the same array twice. In the first loop a recording as added to the array and the array is displayed with 1 element. In the second loop another record is added and the array has now 2 (unique) elements. See as well the answer of Jasny (bold line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`in_array`](http://php.net/in_array) looks for a value inside the array. In you case the values are associated arrays. You may want to check if the key exists

```
if (!isset($arrayRecordings[$recording['id']]))
```

Regardless, the output won't change much, since your loop is replacing the duplicate data. Writing to the same key in an error overwrites the existing data. So there are no duplicates in the `$arrayRecordings` array.

Do note that you're doing a `var_dump` inside of the look, causing you to see each state of the array as it's being build. You might be expecting to so the end result only.

**If you do the `var_dump` outside of the `foreach` loop, you'll see that `$arrayRecordings` doesn't contain any duplicates.**

Comment: Omg. I haven't seen that I have put my `var_dump` inside the foreach. Thank you